# Create new UITableView everytime (not reuse any cell)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with 3 types of custom cells.
Interface in storyboard.

3 different classes in the project for the cells.

I'm doing this currently and the cells IBOutlets are coming out to be nil.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = ListCell()
    cell.configureCell(Data[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}


class ListCell : UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var selectButton: UIButton!

func configureCell(data: ParamList) {
    selectButton.setTitle("Select " + data.name, forState: .Normal)
}

@IBAction func selectButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(selectButton.currentTitle)
}

}
```

I don't want to reuse any cells because every cell has different properties.
Some have textboxes other have different interactive matter which needs to be submitted in the end to a webservice.

I want to create new cells in memory for every cell.
Max cells will be around 15. So won't have much of a memory problems.

Any way I can Do that??

Comment: If you want to be able to dequeue prototype cells from the storyboard then you will need to create the appropriate number of prototype cells with different reuse identifiers. The other approach is to create your UI elements programatically and not use storyboard dequeue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally solve this.
Here's what I did for the same.
I am describing my process if anyone else wanna do the same.

Warning, only do this if absolutely necessary and you do not have that many cells that can affect the performance.

For making UITableView's cells to remain in memory even if scrolled outside the screen encapsulate your table view in a scroll view, and set your UITableView's scrollEnabled to false.

If using Storyboards set a height constraint to your TableView and make an IBOutlet to your code file.

Programatically add new cells with different identifiers.

`"\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"`

After getting your data, set your tableView's height to a multiplier of your data count.

i.e.

`tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = heightOfOneCell * data.count
 tableView.delegate = self
 tableView.dataSource = self`

This way you can scroll with the scrollView and all your cell will still be in the memory.

Answer (score -3):

Set **nil** inside the method **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**. So you can get what number of cells you want in memory.